# Terraform: check if secret exists into azure vault

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform for Azure deployment and I'm trying to store ssh key in Azure vault. I would like to create and store the ssh key if the key doesn't exist in the vault otherwise I would like to reuse the key if exist.

Here is what I tried

1. first create the vault independently since it's containing all my keys
2. Use data to test if the key exist but I always get an error line 11 when the key doesn't exist. I cannot figure out how to do it.
3. NOTE: tls_private_key must not be re-run because the ssh key will change.

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_transverse" {
  name = "k8s-transversal-rg"
}


# Retrieving vault
data "azurerm_key_vault" "data-cluster-vault" {
  name                  = "k8s-transverse-vault"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_transverse.name
}
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "data-cluster-key-public-openssh" {
  name = "cluster-key-public-openssh" 
  key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.data-cluster-vault.id}" 
}
output "secret_value2" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.data-cluster-key-public-openssh.value}"
}

# Creating ssh key only if doesn't exist
 resource "tls_private_key" "cluster-key" {
   count = (data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.data-cluster-key-public-openssh.value == "" ) ? 1 : 0
   algorithm   = "RSA"
   rsa_bits    = "4096"
 }

# store ssh key into vault if created
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "cluster-key-public-openssh" {
  depends_on = [tls_private_key.cluster-key]
  count = (data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.data-cluster-key-public-openssh.value == "" ) ? 1 : 0
  name         = "cluster-key-public-openssh"
  value        = tls_private_key.cluster-key[count.index].public_key_openssh
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.data-cluster-vault.id
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The actual key-vault API has not provide an 'key-exists' test function (beside some ways to achieve this in C# code/API as mentioned in other answers).

IMHO I think you could get away with reading the key and catching the error, see this try-and-continue approach from Terraform:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html

Thus you would create your vault (step 1),then use the try function to read the key in your step 2.
NOTE: try(..) works by eating the errors and continuing with its second parameter. Thus you first read the key in first parameter and in second parameter create the key.

Comment: Hi, I cannot figure out how to write a correct statement for the try command. How can I get access to the resource in the first try argument since I cannot declare the resource without an error?